# Using variable in mod_rewrite on redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following code, that works perfectly but my problem is I dont want to birds hard coded in RewriteRule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /birds/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I dont want to add it manually because there are many folders like "birds"

Example:

from

```
http://domain.com/birds/x.html/
```

to

```
http://domain.com/birds/x.html
```

but in my case it returns to

```
http://domain.com/x.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **capture full URI path** from `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `RewriteRule` which is relative to current directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.*)/$
RewriteRule /$ %1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: it works!! Thank you! is it possible to remove double slashes in same code?

Comment: No issues, accepting an answer is good enough. You will soon have `15` reps to be able to upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want a rewrite map.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html

Then you can do the following

```
RewriteMap MyDirs "txt:/etc/apache2/mydirs.txt"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/?$ /${MyDirs:$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: but these folder names are dynamically generated, I cannot add them to the list. is there a way of using * or something to say, "just remove the trailing slash, no matter which folders" ?

Comment: okay a request url look like this `/something/else` and you want to rewrite it to `/birds/something/else/` right? If not then please post some example requests which you want to rewrite. thanks

Comment: All I want is remove the trailing slash from the url "domain/birds/x.html/" but in my case it returns to domain.com/x.html which should be "domain.com/birds/x.html"

Comment: Ah that's another case. How about this `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: it returns to domain.com/x.html, but I want it to return to domain.com/birds/x.html

Comment: strange ?! Maybe you need to add the first **/** and use per dir a matching pattern `RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/$ /$1/$2 [L,R=301]`

Comment: I have tested but it does not remove the last slash

Comment: still no luck, RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*) /$1/$2 [L,R=301]